# Bind GRPC server interceptor with annotation

Tags: java, grpc

I want to get calling method details on Server interceptor.For eg I want to check if calling method has been annotated only then i want to processing in my server interceptor?Basically i want to bind Server Interceptor with annotation...

I have tried binding annotation with server interceptor which doesnt work

Comment: Most probably the answer is "no you cannot check the calling method annotations in a server interceptor" but can you provide an  example of what you are trying to do - esp on the calling side.